# Calculus in Moment Generating Function

Tags: moment-generating-function, calculus

On page 156 of the Statistics textbook, "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis" by John A. Rice, I came up with two questions on the section about Moment Generating Functions:

1.
[image]

Why are we allowed to shift $d/dt$ to the right of the integral sign? I see that the variable of integration is not $t$, but is there some analysis theorem that the author is taking for granted? We know that the derivative of a sum containing finitely many terms is equal to the sum of those terms' derivatives, so does that extend to this case where there are uncountably many summands for an integral over an interval within the real number set?

2.
[image]

If we know that mgt $M(t)$ exists for all $t$ in an open interval containing zero (call it $I$), why does that imply that $M(t)$ is differentiable (let alone $r^{th}$ differentiable) at $t=0$? Couldn't $M(t)$ have a jump discontinuity at $t=0$ and still exist in $I$? Even if we knew that $M(t)$ was continuous at $t=0$, why would that imply differentiability at $t=0$?

Comment: Both your questions follow from the Leibniz rule. When you have a parametric integral, if the derivative of the function being integrated exists, is integrable and is uniformly dominated (with respect to $x$) by an integrable function of $t$ only, then the parametric integral is differentiable and you can get its derivative by switching integral and derivation.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good account at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule.

Comment: A useful intermediate-level explanation of the assumptions being invoked here can be found in *"Section 2.4 Differentiating under an integral sign" in Casella and Berger (2002)*. Its appeal is perhaps an intuitive exposition of how to assess whether the move is valid without recourse to formal asepcts of analysis or measure theory.